# Change cell color with a conditional formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to change the color of a cell based on its value and I dont want to use conditional formatting tools. I need to know how it can be written on formula bar.

What I have is here with the contitions that I want:

=IF(PMT($G$6;$K34;L$21)<-3000;"";PMT($G$6;$K30;L$21))&IF(PMT($G$6;$K34;L$21)<2000;**change cell color here**;PMT($G$6;$K34;L$21))

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no Excel formula to change a cell color. That functionality is exactly what conditional formatting is designed for. You will have to use conditional formatting to get the result you want.